# Sorry to reach out to you “cold” like this

Tags: expressions

One of my colleague has emailed and started with line 'Sorry to reach out to you “cold” like this'. I am not quite sure what actually does than mean. Can anybody explain it to me.

Thanks
--sachin

Comment: "Cold" in the intended sense comes form the phrase "cold calling," which refers to commercial calls to potential prospects (customers) without any prior contact or other preparatory basis for proceeding with the call. The idea is that the person contacted you without warning or prior agreement, so you are understandably unprepared for the email message—and by acknowledging this, the emailer is acknowledging (and preemptively apologizing for) the fact that the circumstances surrounding the contact aren't ideal, whatever the subject of the message may be.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cold+call